# Getting rid of default html header styles?

Tags: html, css

I red somewhere that search engines like header tags to figure out the content or whatever. I'd like to use them but they just gunk up my style. I tried a style nullifier css file but since it addresses the text in question more precisely than my container class, it overrides the css defined there too. I guess I could just slap on !important to everything or create my own header styles but that would be messy since they aren't always supposed to look the same from page to page.

What would be the simplest way to completely erase any default styling on the header tags?

my html looks like this:

```
<div class="FancyBoxTitle">
    <h1>fancy title goes here</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) is definitely the easiest way, just be sure to load the reset before loading your custom stylesheet and then your styles will override the reset. You should avoid using `!important` at all costs.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

EDIT: i saw someone above refering to **css reset**, others may refer to **css normalize**, BUT this two stylesheet have resets or "stylings" that might not apply to your case, thus its better to use specific "resets" than a whole bunch of useful and useless css rules that you may never need and just pile up as a big css rule bloat.

Comment: with that h1 is still big and bold, I could get rid of the big by adding font-size:100% but can't figure out how to remove the bold without enforcing some value

Comment: if you add a value to your body font size, like font-size:14px; and add font-size:inherit; into the ruleset i wrote you above, then the font-size of all headings would be 14px; from then you can custom override each heading font-size accordingly. you can do the same for font-weight.Beware that any body stylings must be on top of any heading stylings in order to override headings font style. The best thing you can do is trace where your headings get their styling by inspecting in the devtools. If you are using any css frameworks and such again your custom css rules must be loaded last.